# Kubernetes PersistentVolume on local machine, share data

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to spin up a Pod on my local machine. Inside the pod is a single container with a .jar file in it. That jar file can take in files, process then, and then output them. I would like to create a PersistentVolume and attach that to the Pod, so the container can accesss the files.

My Dockerfile:

```
 FROM openjdk:11

 WORKDIR /usr/local/dat

 COPY . .

 ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "./tool/DAT.jar"]
```

(Please note that the folder used inside the container is /usr/local/dat)

My PersistentVolume.yml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: dat-volume
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 150Mi
  storageClassName: hostpath
  hostPath:
    path: /home/zoltanvilaghy/WORK/ctp/shared
```

My PersistentVolumeClaim.yml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dat-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
  storageClassName: hostpath
  volumeName: dat-volume
```

My Pod.yml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dat-tool-pod
  labels:
    name: dat-tool-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: dat-tool
    image: dat_docker
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    args: ["-in", "/usr/local/dat/shared/input/Archive", "-out", "/usr/local/dat/shared/output/Archive2", "-da"]
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /usr/local/dat/shared
        name: dat-volume
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
    - name: dat-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: dat-pvc
```

If all worked well, after attaching the PersistentVolume (and putting the Archive folder inside the shared/input folder), by giving the arguments to the jar file it would be able to process the files and output them to the shared/output folder.

Instead, I get an error saying that the folder cannot be found. Unfortunately, after the error the container exists, so I can't look around inside the container to check the file structure. Can somebody help me identify the problem?

Edit: Output of `kubectl get sc, pvc, pv` :

```
NAME                                             PROVISIONER          RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE



                                                                                                    

storageclass.storage.k8s.io/hostpath (default)   docker.io/hostpath   Delete          Immediate           false                  20d

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

NAME                            STATUS   VOLUME       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE

                                                                                                                                   

persistentvolumeclaim/dat-pvc   Bound    dat-volume   150Mi      RWO            hostpath       4m52s

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

NAME                          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM             STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE

                                                                                                      

persistentvolume/dat-volume   150Mi      RWO            Retain           Bound    default/dat-pvc   hostpath                4m55s
```

Comment: If the goal of the process is to read and write local files, can you just run the process directly, using a local JVM?  As a multi-host clustered container system, Kubernetes doesn't seem like a great match for this.

Comment: The idea would be to have this docker image in the cloud, and when the required folder is uploaded, spin up a container automatically to begin the process. For that kubernetes seems to be the right choice. And to give access to the folder for the container, volumes seem to be needed.

Comment: How do the files "get to the cloud"?  A typical approach here would be to have your application handle HTTP requests, rather than try to act on local files.

Comment: I will be writing a controller method, that takes a .zip folder, extracts the folder within, and saves it to the PersistentVolume. Then I'd use kubernetes to create a Pod with a PersistentVolumeClaim that attaches itself to the volume where I put the folder, and process the files within, and output the results to the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed your sc/pvc/pv are all correct, here's how you can test:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dat-tool-pod
  labels:
    name: dat-tool-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: dat-tool
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    command: ["ash","-c","sleep 7200"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/local/dat/shared
      name: dat-volume
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: dat-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: dat-pvc
```

After the pod is created then you can `kubectl exec -it dat-tool-pod -- ash` and `cd /usr/local/dat/shared`. Here you can check the directory/files (incl. permission) to understand why your program complaint about missing directory/files.

Comment: I did try mounting the volume directly in the Pod definition, but that didn't work either. Afterwards I tried using PersistentVolumes and PersistentVolumeClaims, because later I will be working on the cloud, and afaik this is the better practive. I tried the link you sent, but it doesn't seem to help me. Can you tell me why the code I linked in my question is incorrect?

Comment: The answer assumed when you try to mount to the hostPath has failed. `error saying that the folder cannot be found` - what folder to be exact? Also can you update your question with the output of `kubectl get sc,pvc,pv -n <namespace if not default>`

Comment: On my machine, at /home/zoltanvilaghy/WORK/ctp location I have a /shared folder. Inside that folder I have an /input folder, and inside that I put a folder named Archive. Inside that /Archive folder I have files, which the DAT.jar would be able to process, and output to the /shared/output folder. I manually added the input Archive folder on my machine, and after mounting, I'd expect the folder to appear inside the container. The error is thrown by the DAT.jar file, I can see it after checking the logs of the container: `Input path (/usr/local/dat/shared/input/Archive) does not exist.`

Comment: Clearly this is a one node (minikube?) system. Updated the answer to your comment.

Comment: Currently it is a one node system, using Docker Desktop, and that program's Kubernetes extension. Using the .yml file you have given above, I managed to ssh into the container, and while the folder exists, the folders I have put into the volume on my host machine did not appear. Creating a file inside the container did not appear on my host machine either.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this problem, here is what helped me find a solution:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7023

(And actually the link inside the first comment in this issue.)

So my setup was a Windows 10 machine, using WSL2 to run docker containers and kubernetes cluster on my machine. No matter where I put the folder I wanted to share with my Pod, it didn't appear inside the pod. So based on the link above, I created my folder in /mnt/wsl, called /mnt/wsl/shared.

Because supposedly, this /mnt/wsl folder is where the DockerDesktop will start to look for the folder that you want to share. I changed my PersistentVolume.yml to the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: dat-volume
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 150Mi
  storageClassName: hostpath
  hostPath:
    path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/shared
```

My understanding is that /run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl is the same as /mnt/wsl, and so I could finally pass files between my Pod and my machine.